# Can't link to my bower_components folder using google web-starter-kit

Tags: bower

My problem is I can't link to the `bower_componets` folder.

I am using [web-starter-kit](https://developers.google.com/web/starter-kit/), and basically took those files into my dev environment/folder structure. I know that defeats the purpose of WSK, however I created a gulp work flow and  [wanted to try it out.](https://gist.github.com/antonioOrtiz/2bf2e27b8e0a23115034)

This is what i get in the console. [image]

And this is my folder structure...

[image: folder structure]

I am positive based on where the 'bower_components' folder exists this should be the path.

```
    <script src="../../app/_bower_components/flowtype/flowtype.js"></script>
```

e.g. Start out of in development, then out of builds and dive into 'app'
Is there a bower config file that I am supposed to create?

Comment: I got the answer to my question [here!][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25629491/how-is-gulp-bower-used-and-what-is-it-for