# How is gulp-bower used and what is it for?

Tags: bower, gulp

I am trying to solve this [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25609373/cant-link-to-my-bower-components-folder-using-google-web-starter-kit); Apparently when I use my [gulp](https://gist.github.com/antonioOrtiz/2bf2e27b8e0a23115034) file I can't link to my bower_components folder.

While trying to come up with a solution, I heard of [gulp-bower](https://www.npmjs.org/package/gulp-bower) But the docs seem a little vague. So what is gulp-bower used for? Could this help me?

Anyone run into my problem? Is my gulp file too verbose...

Just as a FYI I set up a components folder which houses index, scss, images and js and I use gulp to stream to a DEV or PROD depending on the situation. But alas I think that maybe the problem...

**PATH STRUCTURE**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*This was supposed to be an answer to your original question, but it's suitable here as well.*

You can't refer to scripts that are out on top of serving directory of your web server.
You could however link to it, if you're on linux, that would be a `ln -s`.

But, there's a better way. Add `.bowerrc` to where you install your bower components from, and add this to it:

```
{
 "directory": "folder/in/a/serving/directory"
}
```

Comment: So `.bowerrcc` will be placed in the same dir as my `bower_components` folder?

Comment: It needs to reside in cwd when you run bower install.

Comment: My index.html is still giving me 404 errors...

    `<link href="../../bower_components/uikit/dist/css/uikit.css" rel="stylesheet">`

Comment: You can't just use `../../` from your top level serving directory, I already told you that. The solution is to have your bower components at least within the same directory (A common layout suggests it to reside within `vendor/` folder somewhere). The `.bowerrc` solution works by doing just that; when you run `bower install` it'll store them to a directory you provided.

Comment: Hey thanks for your help, but keep in mind occasionally some folks are more visual, It didn't click at first...
Anyway, thanks you helped me a great deal!

Comment: @AntonioOrtiz I apologize, it looked to me that you're on the above newbie level; so I assumed you'd knew that. Anyhow, keep coding buddy, gulp is neat btw ;)

Comment: Awe it's ok. The truth is I think I had been banging my head with that one since yesterday, and perhaps was a bit delirious and of embarrassed that I couldn't figure it out!
Thanks for that and your help; Same to you pal! :)

Comment: @iccthedral It should be `"directory"` instead, with the quotes. .bowerrc is in JSON :)